# C++ Passing a long string to constructor or setter

Tags: c++, c++11, parameter-passing, glib, stdstring

I have a class with a Glib::ustring member (if you're not familar with it, assume it's std::string) which is expected to contain a long string, i.e. at lest one paragraph, maybe a few more. Maybe even more than 10 paragraphs. The string is planned to be displayed in a GUI, so maybe in the future it will be stored in the text widget's buffer, but for now it's just a string member object of my C++ class.

The question is: how to pass a string to the constructor, and how to pass it to the set_string() setter method. A long string means a big copy, so I though a good solution would be to take an rvalue reference and std::move the argument into the member object. But I also don't want the class interface to be suprising and hard to use/understand. You know, the rule of least surprise.

So I was thinking, what's the expected/common solution in this case?

(for the setter method here's another option: since editing is done in GUI, just let the GUI edit the string directly, and then the only use of the setter method is to completely replace the string programatically, e.g. reset it or undo a recent edit)

```
class MyClass
{
public:
     explicit MyClass (Glib::ustring str);
     void set_string (Glib::ustring str);
private:
     Glib::ustring str;
}
```

(I've seen code of existing libraries, e.g. gtkmm, taking strings by const reference, but I also saw SO posts with answers saying pass-by-value to allow optimization)

Comment: pass the string by reference.

Comment: @Aeluned bad advice: pass by *value* if you are going to copy it anyhow.  Then `move` out of the copied argument.  Let the compiler do the copy at the call sight instead of hiding it within the body of the method, and optimizations become available that are missing with the copy-in-body version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/

Your function should take the `string` by value, assuming your `string` has an efficient move-constructor.

When you expect that a string will be long, the caller calls `std::move` and passes the value to the setter/constructor.  This isn't surprising, because `std::move` makes it pretty explicit that you are moving the data.

If your system has no more than a modest amount of concurrency, and you rarely modify strings (really, most strings are shared far more than they are modified) shared pointers to immutable strings is actually a pretty useful pattern.  (The shared write data is the reference count, so with high levels of concurrency can cause contention)

Comment: But if I want to allow std::move I need to write a constructor which takes std::string&& parameter, right? And then the caller can pass std::move(my_str)

Comment: No, you can just take a constructor that takes a `string`, and then if you `std::move` it is moved into that parameter, and if you don't `std::move` it is copied into that parameter.  The idea is to do the possible copy at argument passing.

Comment: Then I have another question: Why do constructors (or any other function) ever need to take rvalue reference parameters?

Comment: Example: std::list::emplace() http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace

Comment: Without rvalue references, `move` cannot be efficient.  In effect, you are passing on the work for efficient `move` to the classes themselves (who have rvalue reference `move` constructors), rather than duplicating it (by having your own rvalue reference `move` argument).  The turtles do not go all the way down, but the code you write can usually ride a turtle.

Comment: @fr33domlover that isn't an rvalue reference "really".  `&&` in type deduction context behaves differently (as a universal reference) than `&&` elsewhere.  `&&` in that context allows it to engage in perfect forwarding of the arguments.

Comment: What if my string class doesn't have a move constructor? Unfortunately the string class I use was written before C++11

Comment: `std::move`  will do nothing without support from the class regardless.  That support can be passive in some cases, but probably not here.  You could use rvalue ref to try to swap if that is supported.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for references (not only passing them but also storing a reference). However, a setter has to re-seat the reference, which isn't possible. If you really need to change the string after construction, you have to use pointers (maybe smart pointers).

Depending on the surrounding code you might want to use shared ownership of a string. In this case, I'd use a `std::shared_pointer<GLib::ustring>`. *If you need a setter*. (Otherwise, a reference is better.)

Please note that "some paragraphs" aren't *very long* strings. In user interfaces, a couple of milliseconds of delay, let's say when loading some text file, is totally acceptable. As always: please first profile your code, detect the bottleneck, then optimize if you need it to be faster.

Comment: Of course, I just want to make a design decision before I use the interface. (It's easier to make an educated decision now, than to load a long text file later and realize I need to change the interface and possibly break existing code)